# Styling the JQuery UI Slider

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, styles

This is my markup for the JQuery UI slider

```
<li class = "volume">
    <div class = "slider-vertical" style="height:50px; margin-left:4px;
     margin-top:-60px; background-color: black;" hidden></div>
</li>
```

I have used an inline styling for this. my question is that how come the color of the jquery slider is not changing? even though I've set it to black?

Comment: You should avoid inline styling and use jQuery's CSS selectors instead (e.g. .ui-widget-content).

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: Check out the theming tab at http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/. Also, open an example from the jQuery UI site and look at how the jQuery CSS is being applied. You can either edit the CSS or override it.

Comment: I've only applied inline styling for fast result and to easily see if it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to apply inline styles to the slider, you should use [jQuery UI Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) to style your UI components and generate a custom CSS file for your implementation.

Lots of the jQuery UI components utilize images as the background so updating the background color often will not have the desired effect. Using the Themeroller will give you the best possible results.